# Frogger game using pygame: frog is not drawn on the window

Tags: python, class, pygame

this is how my code looks like. I suppose to draw frog on the window and make a movement. I suppose this should work, but , but the code doesn't even get to the mainRun event part. How should I fix it?

```
### Run Game
class MainRun(object):
    # init function to initialize all the class 

    def __init__(self): 
        self.frog = Frog()


    def run(self): 
        print("a")
        while True:
            print("b")
            self.frog.draw(window)
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        frog.move("left")
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        frog.move("right")
                    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        frog.move("up")
                    if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                        frog.move("down")
                # add player updates here
            self.frog.draw(window)
            pygame.display.update()
            windowClock.tick(60)

            window.fill(white)

if __name__ == __main__:

    MainRun()
```

Answer (score 0):

You just instantiation your class.If you want to run the method run.Should add code after 'main':

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = MainRun()
    m.run()
```